# PHP - why is generating a text area per line when attempting to echo in a text area?

Tags: php, forms, echo

Why can not I make an echo inside a textarea after doing a foreach? the echo happens yes, but everything comes in fragments, one line in each text area.

Why does not everything come out in the same text area?

```
$array = end($matches);
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
foreach ($array as $strX) {
$strX = 'myprefix'.$strX.'<br>';
//echo $strX;
echo '<textarea>'.$strX.'</textarea>';
}
```

Comment: Extend your code to form a [mcve]. This makes it easier for everyone to understand your problem and check if a possible solution is correct. [edit] your post to that effect to increase your chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the value and then echo into the textarea.

```
$value = null;
foreach ($array as $strX) {
    $value .= 'myprefix'.$strX.PHP_EOL;
}

echo '<textarea>'.$value.'</textarea>';
```

https://3v4l.org/KZn2M

Comment: Its solution is excellent, being able to have the freedom to work with data outside the loop. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego It also works too, others just ouput `<textarea></textarea>`, which I assume that was not what you wanted :/

Comment: I was using the text area to collect the data manually by copying and pasting into another field, I really just wanted a text area, but its solution, made me change my code for better, now the data goes straight to the field I was pasting manually! Thanks you for your very intelligent solution!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Well, we just do `<textarea>` as a fix for her code, we weren't asked to enhance it. Moreover, a more suitable place for code enhancements is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you so far. You just need to put the beginning tag of `textarea` before the for-loop. So your code would become:

```
$array = end($matches);
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
echo '<textarea>';
foreach ($array as $strX) {
$strX = 'myprefix'.$strX.'<br>';
//echo $strX;
}
echo '</textarea>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. you Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put textarea outsside loop

```
$array = end($matches);
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);

echo '<textarea>';
foreach ($array as $strX) {
$strX = 'myprefix'.$strX.'<br>';
//echo $strX;
}
echo '</textarea>';
```